# Does anybody know how to make the other A as a B ? I added the pic for reference

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

[image]
This is how my work is supposed to look like.

[image]
And this is my work.

--->

```
<li class="roman">1950-1990</li>
      
          <ol class="one">
              <div class="Sub" ><li>Romantic</li> </div>
         <ol> <li >The Tale of the White Serpent</li>
          <li >Candy Candy</li>
          <li >Neighborhood Story</li></ol>
            </ol>
              
        
          
          <ol class="one">
              <div class="Sub"><li>Action</li></div>
          <ol><li>Treasure Island</li>
          <li>Mobile Suit Gundam</li>
          <li>Doraemon</li></ol>
        </ol>
```

```
.Sub {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

I tried using a the ol tag and adding type="a" but that didn't work. If anyone can help me I am struck please.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `<ol>` tag too many times.  Unordered lists (`<ul>...</ul>`) and ordered lists (`<ol>...</ol>`) are containers for `<li>...</li>` elements.

```css
.roman { list-style-type: upper-roman; }
.letter { list-style-type: upper-alpha; }
.number { list-style-type: decimal; }
```

```html
<ol class="roman">
  <li>1950-1990</li>
  <ol class="letter">
    <li>Romantic</li>
    <ol class="number">
      <li>The Tale of the White Serpent</li>
      <li>Candy Candy</li>
      <li>Neighborhood Story</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Action</li>
    <ol class="number">
      <li>Treasure Island</li>
      <li>Mobile Suit Gundam</li>
      <li>Doraemon</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>
</ol>
```